Parted Error: The location XXMB is outside of the device /dev/xxx
I'm trying to manually create a distro on my SD card, starting with creating partitions and it's failing...
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    1 119.4G  0 disk 
vda    254:0    0    12G  0 disk 
├─vda1 254:1    0   300M  0 part /boot
└─vda2 254:2    0  11.7G  0 part /
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=${SDCARD} bs=1M count=32
32+0 records in
32+0 records out
33554432 bytes (34 MB, 32 MiB) copied, 0.0249871 s, 1.3 GB/s
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sda mklabel gpt
$ sudo parted -s /dev/sda mkpart fat32 32MB 512MB
Error: The location 512MB is outside of the device /dev/sda.

What could be the potential cause for this?

haven't used parted for a while, but "primary" in the context of GPT makes no sense ("primary partition" is a concept introduced specifically for DOS-style partition tables when it became obvious the original scheme was insufficiently advanced. That was  in 1987; GPT, a late-1990's concept, has none of these problems and hence doesn't have "primary" or "extended" partitions.) Does it work if you remove primary from your mkpart line?

Nope. Same error
